# Docker service 'cm' failed to build

Tags: powershell, docker

I am setting up the `Sitecore` project with `docker` and getting the following error :

> Service 'cm' failed to build: Build failed

[image]

While running the `docker-compose build` in the `Powershell` script.

The docker desktop containers look like this:
[image]

Is there any way to solve this issue?

**Note: IIS is stopped**

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile?

Comment: As well as what variables you are providing in the build process.

Comment: I will revisit all the changes done to default docker files and look for potential root cause. Is it the first Move-File step that failed or the previous Move-Item steps succeeded but only this one failed. A few quick tips that usually help to resolve such issues is checking if Containers is enabled in windows features and having hyper-v enabled for Docker.

Comment: @Ghanendra both the options are already checked in windows and only this step is getting failed all other previous are successfully completed

Answer (score 1):

You can cross check few things

1. Use `docker compose v2` is unchecked

[image]

2. Make sure other services are stopped or run the below commands:

- `get-service w3svc | Stop-Service`
- `Stop-Service MSSQLSERVER`
- `get-service *xconnect* | Stop-Service`
- `get-service *solr* | Stop-Service`

3. Make sure the specified folder/current user has rights to update the folder
4. See docker logs for details
5. Sometimes the docker command gives issue but when again we do `Compose down` and then `up`, it works.

These are some basic steps, may be you can if it solve your issue, else you can share log details here.